# How do I find out if a polynomial is irreducible?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I have this polynomial:

$f(x)=x^4+x^3-4x^2-5x-5$. How can I find out if this polynomial is irreducible over the field $\mathbb{Q}$ of rational numbers? I know about mod $p$ irreducibility test but it fails in this case. In general how do you find out if a polynomial is irreducible or prove that it is reducible?

Comment: Do you know about Eisenstein's criterion?

Comment: @AWertheim I have read about that theorem but I was unable to use it in this case. It says I have to find a prime p which does not divide $a_4$ (1), divides $a_3, a_2, a_1$ and $p^2$ does not divide $a_0$. How can I apply that theorem here?

Comment: Since this one is reducible, Eisenstein won't help.

Comment: @khajvah: as Robert Israel notes, your polynomial is reducible. But it is a general technique for showing a polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. Note that you need not always consider $f(x)$ - you can apply Eisenstein's criterion equally well to $f(x+k), k\in \mathbb{Z}$, which sometimes yields the desired conclusion.

Comment: @AWertheim So in conclusion, we might be able to prove that a polynomial is irreducible but it is impossible to prove that it is reducible without actually finding the factors ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Being a quartic, this polynomial is reducible if and only if it has a linear or quadratic factor with integer coefficients.

A linear factor implies an integer root.  The only possible roots are $1,-1,5,-5$.  Checking, none of them works.  Note that for $x=\pm5$ you don't need to do all the calculations since it is easy to see that then
$$x^4+x^3-4x^2-5x-5\equiv-5\pmod{25}$$
and so LHS${}\ne0$.

So try
$$x^4+x^3-4x^2-5x-5=(x^2+ax+b)(x^2+cx+d)\ .$$
Expanding and equating coefficients,
$$a+c=1\ ,\quad ac+b+d=-4\ ,\quad ad+bc=-5\ ,\quad bd=-5\ .$$
The last equation gives four possibilities for $b$ and $d$, (in fact only two, as we may assume by symmetry that $b=\pm1$ and $d=\pm5$) and then it's easy to find the other coefficients:

- $b=-1$, $d=5$, $a=(b+5)/(b-d)=-\frac23$, didn't work;
- $b=1$, $d=-5$, $a=(b+5)/(b-d)=1$, $c=1-a=0$,

and we then check that
$$x^4+x^3-4x^2-5x-5=(x^2+x+1)(x^2-5)\ .$$

**Note** that if our second attempt above had failed, this would be enough to conclude that the polynomial is irreducible.

Answer (score 4):

There are algorithms, e.g. [Kronecker's](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Kronecker_method), that will find factors over $\mathbb Q$ if they exist.  These are implemented in the various Computer Algebra systems, so in practice you would just ask Maple or [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=is%20%20x%5E4%20%2B%20x%5E3%20%20-%204*x%5E2%20-%205*x%20-%205%20irreducible).

Comment: I got this in my test and was unable to solve. I doubt my professor wanted us to google the result. Is `mod p irreducibility test` reliable?